# soundcloud api python user information

Tags: python, api, soundcloud

Issues using SoundCloud API with python to get user info

I've downloaded the soundcloud library and followed the tutorials, and saw on the soundcloud dev page that user syntax is, for example /users/{id}/favorites.

I just don't know how to use python to query user information.  Specifically, i would like to print a list of tracks that a given user liked, (or favorited, but liked would be better).

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, pretty simple just didn't know the exact syntax.

```
users = client.get('/users', g ='keyword')
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, It's better to mention what you have tried and show some code. It makes it easier for people to help you on Stack Overflow. Regardless maybe looking at [SoundCloud's Python wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following :

import soundcloud

token= 'user_access_token'

client = soundcloud.Client(access_token=token)

user_info = client.get('/me')

user_favorites = client.get('/me/favorites')

user_tracks = client.get('/me/tracks')

and so on...